# (OpenWRT) Mqtt service command is not working via C, Lua

Tags: c, lua, mqtt, mosquitto, openwrt

i've installed mqtt at my router and uses WEB UI to control this.
here are some lines that i added into  *mosquitto.conf*

```
user root
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
```

here are some part of the lua script.

```
if mqttOnOff == "1" then // mqttOnOff is setted at WEB UI.
    os.execute("service mosquitto enable")
    os.execute("echo \"mosquitto service is enabled\" > /dev/console")
    os.execute("service mosquitto stop")
    os.execute("echo \"mosquitto service is stopped\" > /dev/console")
    os.execute("service mosquitto start")
    os.execute("echo \"mosquitto service is started\" > /dev/console")
elseif mqttOnOff == "0" then
    os.execute("service mosquitto disable")
    os.execute("echo \"mosquitto service is disabled\" > /dev/console")
    os.execute("service mosquitto stop")
    os.execute("echo \"mosquitto service is stopped\" > /dev/console")
else
    os.execute("echo \"mqttOnOff value returned with error\" > /dev/console")
end
```

whenever i set *mqttOnOff*'s value to 1, i can see following lines at console

```
mosquitto service is enabled
mosquitto service is stopped
mosquitto service is started
```

if i set value to 0, obviously i can see...

```
mosquitto service is disabled
mosquitto service is stopped
```

anyways, this means service commands are being executed with *os.execute()*
However, it doesn't work.

whenever i manually input those commands at console with my fingers, it works. it stops well, it starts well, it restarts well, it enables well, it disables well.

but everytime i use lua's *os.execute* doesn't work.

i manually start mosquitto and set with WEB UI  to enable(start)again and check the PID with *ps*, PID shows same(should be different since command has serevice mosquitto *stop* and *start*). if i set with WEB UI to disable(start), it does not stops.

Manually stopping mosquitto and set with WEB UI to enable, does not starts.

So, i used C, instead of lua. Mechanism is same. just using *system()* function since it's C.

```
if (mqttOnOff == 1)
{
    system("service mosquitto enable");
    system("echo enable > /dev/console");
    system("service mosquitto stop");
    system("echo stop > /dev/console");
    system("service mosquitto start");
    system("echo start > /dev/console");
}
else if (mqttOnOff == 0)
{
    system("service mosquitto disable");
    system("echo disable > /dev/console");
    system("service mosquitto stop");
    system("echo stop > /dev/console");
}
```

Same as the lua, i can see

```
enable
stop
start
```

when i set via WEB UI, even if manually execute this compiled C file.

Result is the same. mqtt is not starting.

any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution!!

Since `service` is not executeable, instead of using `service`, i just executed mosquitto via mosquitto command.

https://forum.openwrt.org/t/mqtt-service-command-is-not-working-via-c-lua/116434/2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).